# How to: Group items, retrieve one (random) row data of group and count rows in each group at one SQL clause

Tags: sql, oracle

I have simple table in database where are columns error_id, error_group_id and message. I want to show listing in UI which shows Message and occurrences of each error group.

Error message may vary slightly (for eg: Settings X expired on date) where date may change for example, but error_group_id, which is hash from defined constants which want to be used for grouping, doesn't change (for eg, may be (AssemblyName+"Settings expired").GetHashCode().

Currently I can list the groups with messages:

```
 SELECT message, error_group_id
 FROM (SELECT error_id, message, error_group_id,
 rank() OVER ( PARTITION BY error_group_id ORDER BY error_id) rank
 FROM cc_errors)
 WHERE rank <= 1;
```

Outputs:
(just pick one random) message, group hash. (Only once per group).

However, I want information about how many individual error messages is inside of group (double click group opens window which shows listing of individual errors). I'd like to count occurrences of each group in this SQL clause.

So wanted output is following (single row per group):

message, group hash, count of messages inside of group.

Project is using oracle as database.

Could someone help with this :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a `COUNT` in your current query:

```
SELECT message, error_group_id, cnt
  FROM (SELECT error_id,
               message,
               error_group_id,
               rank() OVER (PARTITION BY error_group_id ORDER BY error_id) rank,
               count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY error_group_id) cnt
          FROM cc_errors)
 WHERE rank <= 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're just looking for `group by`:

```
 select distinct c.message, c.error_group_id, t.error_group_count
   from cc_errors c
           inner join
        (select error_group_id, count(*) as error_group_count
           from cc_errors
          group by error_group_id) t  on t.error_group_id = c.error_group_id
```

This returns what you asked for but doesn't seem to make sense.  I'd do this: return all the messages with the group ids, then when you click on a group id, do a `select count(*) from cc_errors where error_group_id = @groupId`

Comment: Yep i think now that i were doing this too hard way, amount of data is small so i read now everything to dictionary, where group id is the key and value is list of messages in group. For window that shows messages from group i just pass list of message strings.